# Протабулировать функцию

Tags: c++

> Протабулировать функцию y=1-cos(2*x)/2 на промежутке от a до b, разбив его на 30 частей.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include<math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    int a, b, t, i;
    double y;
    printf("Enter a=");
    scanf_s("%i", &a);
    printf("Enter b=");
    scanf_s("%i", &b);
    int sh = (b - a) / 30;
    printf("%i", sh);
    printf("\n");
    for (i = a; i <= b; i += sh)
    {
        y = 1 - cos(2 * i) / 2;
        printf("\nX=%i", i);
        printf("\tF(x)=%3.3f", y);
    }
}
```

Comment: В че именно проблемы?

Comment: Не получается написать, через for

Comment: Что вы уже написали? Напишите без for. Вопрос - "я ничего не знаю, ааа, стипендию снимут" - здесь автоматом идет на закрытие. И вы бы знали об этом, если бы хотя бы прочли первую страницу сайта. Делайте, решайте - тогда и помощь будет. Пока вся помощь - вот: https://code-live.ru/post/cpp-loops/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

шаг `h` определяем следующим образом `h = (b - a) / 'на сколько частей делим'` далее в цикле вызываем `f` с шагом `h` от `a` до `b`

```
#include <iostream>

double f(double x)
{
  return 1 - cos(2 * x) / 2;
}

int main()
{
  double a = 15;
  double b = 30;
  double h = (b - a) / 30;
  double eps = 1e-6;

  b += h / 2;
  for (double x = a; x < b + eps; x += h) {
    std::cout << "f(" << x << ")" << '\t' << "= " << f(x) << '\n';
  }

  return 0;
}
```

`eps` опционально установите самостоятельно

Comment: Ломаете Harry всю педагогическую работу. :)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat в начале пути и на таких задачах ступор бывает уж, просто всякие циклы как обыденные вещи для опытных программистов

Comment: Не очень надёжная конструкция `for (double x = a; x < b; x += h)`. Несмотря на то, что количество промежутков фиксировано и равно `30`, из-за особенностей арифметики с плавающей точкой при разных парах значений `a, b`, цикл может выполняться разное количество раз. См. [пример](https://ideone.com/3DmNDk).

Comment: @wololo спасибо, согласен, можно добавить сравнение с эпсилон

Comment: Верхнюю границу можно взять на полшага больше, и все будет ок. Или еще лучше - цикл делать интом от 1 до <= N, и делать `i / double(N) * (b - a) + a`.

Comment: Всем спасибо. 
В итоге код сам написал.